# Want to use column names as indices, but without quotes

Tags: replacement

The following works:

```
devFactors =SQLExecute[SicsDBconnection, "SELECT * FROM " <>  devFactorTable];
devFactors[[1]]

colNames = {ALOB, Country, Months, LossFactor, EarnedFactor};
asRules = Rule @@@ Transpose[{colNames, Range[Length@colNames]}];
newList[col_] := devFactors[[All, col /. asRules]];
newList[LossFactor][[1]]
```

and produces:

```
{"Property Treaty PR", "Morristown", 12, 3.5736, 3.09256}
3.5736
```

I would like to pull those column names from SQL as the following:

```
colNames = SQLColumnNames[SicsDBconnection, SQLTable[devFactorTable]][[All, 2]];
```

But, when I do this, colNames now is a list of strings instead of a list of symbols and I have to reference my devFactors list like:

```
newList["LossFactor"][[1]]
```

I would like to be able to reference it using the symbol LossFactor instead of the string.  I see that I can't replace the head of an atom, so I think that means that I can't turn those strings from SQL into symbols.

Obviously this isn't a critical problem, but does anyone know how I can accomplish this, or if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `ToExpression[]`:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
conn = OpenSQLConnection["demo"];
devFactorTable = "SAMPLETABLE1"
devFactors = SQLExecute[conn, "SELECT * FROM " <> devFactorTable]
colNames = ToExpression /@ SQLColumnNames[conn, SQLTable[devFactorTable]][[All, 2]];
asRules = Rule @@@ Transpose[{colNames, Range[Length@colNames]}];
newList[col_] := devFactors[[All, col /. asRules]];
newList[NAME][[1]]
CloseSQLConnection[conn]
(*
 "Day1"
*)
```

---

**Edit**

Prior to running this code you've to set up the demo environment for DB connectivity. If you haven't done it yet, just run:

```
<< DatabaseLink`DatabaseExamples`;
DatabaseExamplesBuild[ ]
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I did something that I don't understand.  I put all of the code (from Needs["DatabaseLink`"] to  CloseSQLConnection) in a module and made all of the symbols local, except for newList.  So newList references a local list, devFactors.  But by using ":=" in the definition of newList, doesn't it evaluate when I use it later on in the code?  If so, how does it use the local symbols when I reference it outside of the module?  That is, isn't devFactors gone after I leave the module?

Comment: @MitchellKaplan The garbage collector takes note that the local symbol is referenced from outside and it doesn't swipe it. It's a good question for the site on its own.